# Python3.6: error installing Pylab

Tags: python

There are similar questions posted on Stackoverflow that did not seem to work for me.  I am trying to install the pylab module for Python.  I am using OSX.  I have Python 2.7, 3.6, and 3.7 installed and have been running IDLE from 3.6.  I also installed Anaconda.  It looks like I have the modules and libraries I need here:

```
/Users/[username]/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib
```

There is also a *pylab.py* in that same site-packages directory.
But when I run a simple Python program with:

```
from pylab import plot, show
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[username]/Desktop/Python/graph.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pylab import plot, show
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylab'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Run `YOUR_PYTHON_3.6 -c 'import pylab'` to see any error?

Comment: You are probably running the script using the default python that comes on OS X and not Anaconda Python. Can you execute `which python` and if it doesn't return `/Users/[username]/anaconda3/bin/python` then just add it to you PATH: `export PATH=/Users/[username]/anaconda3/:$PATH`

Comment: pylab is deprecated, use `matplotlib.pyplot` and `numpy` instead.

Comment: haha, beat you by 2 seconds @AndrasDeak ;)

Comment: @danielfrg ran `which python` and path is correct.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque @AndrasDeak  Tried importing `matplotlib.pyplot` and `numpy`.  Got an error `No module named 'matplotlib'`.  It is in this directory:

Comment: `anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib`.  It must be looking in the wrong directory?

Comment: launch `ipython` i/o `python`

Comment: Our remark was tangential to your actual problem. You still need to fix the install issue. If you want to follow our suggestion you must install numpy and matplotlib separately.